# Missing Autodesk.AEC.ModelData in model forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I am trying to access Autodesk.AEC.ModelData data in forge viewer.
I have two revit models.
so while consuming it inside the viewer for the first model have the Autodesk.AEC.ModelData but when I am trying to access Autodesk.AEC.ModelData in 2nd model it returns me empty.

After verifying in postman by calling api I found in the second model
there is no role with the name Autodesk.AEC.ModelData and I could not find any url with AECModelData.json

so I would like to understand where is it going wrong is it problem at translation level or is has to do it with revit software. do we manually need to add AEC data before exporting file to rvt or nwd ?

please let me know any other solution to access this data or the area where I can take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only RVT saved with Revit 2018 and later will generate AecModelData. If you still cannot see it on files of Revit 2018 and later, you can try to translate it again with the `x-ads-force: true` request header.